# How to remove UILabel dynamically while filling a form in popup View into our main view?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i have a form with four text field in popup, if i fill all four text fields and click on save button in it, it shows on our view. But when again i open the popup and fill only three or two fields, its shows all the four fields in view which i filled earlier. Can someone help he how to romove those fields?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the `textFields` are properties. You will need to go to the `viewWillAppear` method and set the the text back to blank text.

So every time the view loads the textFields, you will see them blank.

Comment: if([textView.text length] > 0 && [name.text length] > 0 && [etc.text length] > 0)
 {
  [mycurrParent writeText1:textView.text];
  [mycurrParent writeText22:name.text];
  [mycurrParent writeText333:etc.text];
 } to call those labels and when i use if([name.text length] == 0 && [textView.text length] > 0 && [etc.text length] > 0)
 {
  [mycurrParent writeText1:textView.text];
  [mycurrParent writeText33:etc.text];
      
 }its creating me a problem...

Comment: What is this ? Setting four textfields to intial values is just so easy. Why are you complicating it ?

Answer (score 0):

Removing `UILabel` is easy. If you have a reference to the label then all you need to do is -

```
label = nil;
[label release];
```

If you want to just hide that label - `[label setHidden:YES];`